# How to use ftp client in AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ftp

Anyone here that have a ec2 instance that is on a private subnet in AWS that is able to connect to outside FTP server? It seems that my ec2 instance cannot connect to 3rd party ftp servers without moving to public subnet and using elastic/public ip.

Comment: It seems that i'm not the only one who experienced this issue. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=274820

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private subnet by default have no connectivity to outside world or internet. But there is a resource called [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) that you can configure in your VPC to provide an outgoing internet connectivity from your private subnets.

> You can use a network address translation (NAT) gateway to enable
>   instances in a private subnet to connect to the internet or other AWS
>   services, but prevent the internet from initiating a connection with
>   those instances.

You can follow the link here to setup the NAT gateway.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/

Comment: Ok, but what if the outside world wants to connect to a server inside private subnet. Then how to provide access?

Comment: If the outside world wants to connect to the server in private subnet then you should question whether the server should be in private subnet. You can always setup a public jump/bastion box to get inside your private network.

Answer (score 0):

Private subnets do not have internet connectivity by default. You need to create a nat gateway on the public subnet. Nat gateways are bit expensive. You can also create a nat instance in that case.